# I'm trying to make a frequency table where Var1 only uses one value and Var3 does not appear in the table but filters data in the table

Tags: r, frequency

I'm trying to make a frequency table where VAR1 is some but not all values and VAR3 filters what rows are used to make the table.

ISCED is Var1 and i want only values of 12 and 15. If possible i don't want to see FALSE in my table. Secondly i want to only use the rows where PK_T = 1. Can't figure out how to do it.

```
 My DF 
ISCED    EMTAK    PK_T  
 12       233      1
 12       245      0
 12       233      NA
 13       233      1
 15       433      1
 15       245      0
```

```
 I want
ISCED   EMTAK  Freq
 True    233    1
 True    245    0
 True    433    1
```

Comment: Why has `EMTAK==433` a frequency of `2`?

Comment: It was a mistake. I changed it to the correct value.

Comment: OK. I have updated my answer to the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that your dataset is as you presented it:

```
myDF <- data.frame(ISCED=c(12, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15), EMTAK=c(233, 245, 233, 233, 433, 245), PK_T=c(1, 0, NA, 1, 1, 0))
```

Then using only the **dplyr** package and table() from baseR you can do:

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

newDF <- myDF %>%
  na.omit %>%                        # remove NA values
  filter(PK_T==1) %>%
  filter(ISCED==12 | ISCED==15) %>%
  select(EMTAK) %>%                  # drop the column ISCED
  mutate(Freq= table(.$EMTAK))       # mutate() creates the new column "Freq"
```

Giving:

```
  EMTAK      Freq
1   233         1
2   433         1
```

If you want to do other combinations then you adjust the arguments inside the **filter()**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table` to get the *frequenc*. To include `0` times you can use `as.factor`. You can use `[` to subset to the cases where `x$PK_T==1`. To get only those where ISCED values of 12 or 15 you can use `%in%`:

```
y <- table(as.factor(x$EMTAK)[x$ISCED %in% c(12, 15) &
   !is.na(x$PK_T) & x$PK_T==1])
data.frame(ISCED = TRUE, EMTAK = names(y), Freq = as.vector(y))
#  ISCED EMTAK Freq
#1  TRUE   233    1
#2  TRUE   245    0
#3  TRUE   433    1
```

Or using `aggregate` only if all conditions are true.

```
aggregate(cbind(Freq=PK_T) ~ EMTAK, x[x$ISCED %in% c(12, 15) &
  !is.na(x$PK_T) & x$PK_T==1,], length)
#  EMTAK Freq
#1   233    1
#2   433    1
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="ISCED    EMTAK    PK_T  
 12       233      1
 12       245      0
 12       233      NA
 13       233      1
 15       433      1
 15       245      0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your data and the data.table package, I subset the data to those where ISCED is 12 or 15, group by EMTAK and PK_T == 1 and then use .N to count the number of occurrences, I then chain a second expression to limit to those where ISCED is TRUE. Note I also drop the PK_T variable from the final table - its meaningless as there is no variation in the variable.

```
library(data.table)
dt1[ISCED %in% c(12, 15), .N, by = .(EMTAK, PK_T == 1)][PK_T == TRUE, -"PK_T"]
```

Giving

```
   EMTAK N
1:   233 1
2:   433 1
```

Which is the correct answer with your data, there is only one occurrence of 233 where PK_T is 1, the other occurrence it is an NA.

A base R equivalent would be

```
table(df1[df1$ISCED %in% c(12, 15) & df1$PK_T == 1, "EMTAK"])
```